# C# Vars init, performance and good practice

Tags: c#, performance, variables, initialization

I'm sorry if this thread will be considered as subjective, but my question is more on the technical side.

I'm working with C# in the Framework .Net 4.0. I spent a few years playing with C++ and I've received an education where variables that were not initialized got me a kick in the butt.

Today, each time I see a uninitialized variable in a C# snippet, I do shiver a little bit and I really cannot make up my mind if I should initialize them or not.

I've read many articles where people say that, some are initialized, others not (members vs local), I've read articles where people say that initializing vars in C# gets you in trouble with performance...

In my current application, I want to have good performance but before all, I need to avoid having stupid bugs because of variables that are uninitialized.

What is the best practice regarding this ?

Edit :

```
public MyClass
{
    private int foo; // Is it initialized ? Do I have to ?

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        int bar;  // Is it initialized ? Do I have to ?

        ...
    }
} // Is it a good practice to initialize every vars all the time or not ? 
  // Will I get troubles by not initializing those ?
  // If I do initialize them, will I get performance slowdown ?
```

Comment: The problem is not that the question is subjective, but that it has too wide a scope and is not very clear! Ask a specific question, preferably with a code sample.

Comment: I'm sorry, what don't you understand in my question ? I want to know, if, in C#, ALL variables are automatically initialized, or if there are some cases where there are not. Then, I want to know if having the habit of initializing every variables will take my performances down... Is it better ? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know, if, in C#, ALL variables are automatically
>   initialized, or if there are some cases where there are not

When you declare a reference type variable like instance of `SomeClass`, it's default value will be `null`. Your variable will get initialized once you allocate some memory for it using new

```
SomeClass someClass; //not initialized, it's value is null

someClass = new SomeClass(); //initialized
```

On the other hand value types are initialized when you declare them. For example

```
int bar; //initialized with value 0
```

> Is it a good practice to initialize every vars all the time or not ?

Well, it depends on scenario. For example when you declare a bool it's default value is `false`. But for reader's understanding it's better to explicitly do `bool myBool = false`. On the other hand if you have to pass a variable as `out` to some method, initializing a variable is of no use because it is responsibility of method. It really depends on your scenario and practises you like to follow.

> Will I get troubles by not initializing those ?

If you are fine with default value(uninitialized value) then you won't get in to trouble. But if your code expects some initialized value and your variable is not initialized then you might get into trouble.

> If I do initialize them, will I get performance slowdown?

Nope. If your app's performance is really slow you should use some profiler to find out what is causing slow performance. Initializing variable is very unlikely to cause performance issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read that vars like "int bar;" are initialized only when there are class members, not in local methods, is it correct or not ?

Comment: @hansHasan : but for a local variable, there is no way for a programmer to find out.

Comment: @HenkHolterman no way to find out what exactly? Sorry I didn't get your point

Comment: That the variable has been set to default(T).

Comment: is there any possibility that the local variable won't be initialized with default value? If no, then do programmer need a way to find this out? I think no. Isn't this a safe assumption that a local variable will always be set with default value?

Answer (score 4):

In C# you won't have a problem with uninitialized variables having random values like you do in C/C++.

Some variables (fields/statics for example) are guaranteed to be initialized to their default value (generally null/0), and the compiler give you [an error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d(v=vs.100).aspx) in all cases where a default value is not guaranteed and you've not manually initialized the variable before use.

In other words, if you're not sure, trust the compiler to tell you.

Edit: The reverse is also true, if you manually initialize your local variables in method to their default and the compiler can see that you never use it before changing it, it will remove the initialization for you, so no overhead unless you actually use the value.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing or not initializing a variable in C# depends on what you want to achieve, and both options are valid in different situations.

Take, for example, a class that exposes some properties and you wish the properties to have a default value:

```
public class X 
{
    private object _propertyName;

    public object PropertyName
    {
         get { return _propertyName; }
         set 
         {
             _propertyName = value;
             doSomething();
         }
    }
}
```

In this class, leaving `_propertyName` uninitialized may expose you to a `NullReferenceException` if you try to read the value of the property before it has been set, so initializing it to a suitable default value is good practice here.

However, sometimes you want to provide the option for the user to pass in `null`, in which case, initializing a variable may overwrite this legitimate input.

```
public void doSomethingToObjectInCollection(object key, List<object> haystack)
{
    // First find it in the collection
    object foundValue;
    for( int i = 0; i < haystack.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( haystack[i].KeyField == key )
            foundValue = key;
    }

    if( foundValue != null )
    {
        // Do something here if there was a foundValue
    }
}
```

In this example, initializing foundValue to a default value will create incorrect behaviour. Of course, you can initialize it to `null` explicitly if it is so hard for you to look at, but this doesn't change the behaviour of the code (unlike C++).

As for performance considerations, unfortunately there isn't a "yes it's bad" or "no it's OK" answer. In most applications it is probably not going to matter a great deal, but if you have hard performance requirements then deciding what to do requires a context-specific understanding of exactly what is going on when you do initialize a variable.

Value types will be initialized on allocation to zero, but this is hardly an expensive operation and so likely will not overly concern you.

Reference types are where you may incur a performance hit by initializing values before they are used. For instance:

```
public class TheClass
{
    MyType x = new MyType();

    public TheClass()
    {
        x = new MyType(/*some arguments*/);
    }
}
```

This will result in two allocations for x, the first with the default constructor, the second inside the constructor with new values. This is because class level variables are initialized before the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the answer of Haris Hasan, he tols us the example of "int bar;". But I've read that those lines kind of vars are initialized only when there are class members, not in local methods, is it correct or not ?

Comment: As said above, int will always be initialized to zero. So initializing, for example "int x = 5;" will result in two assignments.